# How to print a list in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I assert student details to DB like this.

```
assert(details(Age,Name,Dob,Zodiac)).
```

I want to get a details list sorted by Age(asending or desending) and display it somethin like this.

```
Name : sam
Date of Birth : 1991-8-1
Age : 23
Zodiac Sign : leo

Name : john
Date of Birth : 1993-6-12
Age : 25
Zodiac Sign : cancer
```

I tried with bagof,findall but could not get a correct answer.
Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear on terminology, `details(Age,Name,Dob,Zodiac)` isn't a *list*. It's a *relation* consisting of a functor (`details`) and 4 arguments. A list would be, `[Age,Name,Dob,Zodiac]`. Also, why not show the code you attempted? And do you ever want to sort by anything other than age?

Comment: I do it like this.    assert(details(23,sam,'1991-8-1',leo)). I read user inputs like name and date of birth. then i calcualte age and Zodiac sign and assert that data to DB. after all user insert their data i want to get a list like above.

Comment: That shows how you're asserting your data, but it's not showing what you attempted to solve your problem of displaying the data.

Comment: I tried this one.    setof(details(A,N,D,S),N^D^S^details(A,N,D,S),Out). but it does not show the list the way i want.

Comment: `setof(details(A,N,D,S),N^D^S^details(A,N,D,S),Out).` should give you the raw list you want, you still have to format it. Also, you don't need the existential quantifiers, `N^D^S^` because you are asking for those variables to be included in your set, although it still gives the same result in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as ordering the facts, using `setof` would be helpful here, assuming your facts are all distinct in some way. `setof` will automatically sort by a natural order, which in this case, will be by the first argument in `details`, which is the age:

```
list_ascending :-
    detail_list(List),
    maplist(write_item, List).

list_descending :-
    detail_list(List),
    reverse(List, DescList),
    maplist(write_item, DescList).

detail_list(List) :-
    setof(details(Age,Name,Dob,Zodiac), details(Age,Name,Dob,Zodiac), List).
```

Then you just need to create your `write_item` predicate:

```
write_item(details(Age,Name,Dob,Zodiac)) :-
    write('Name : '), write(Name), nl,
    write('Date of Birth : '), write(Dob), nl,
    write('Age : '), write(Age), nl,
    write('Zodiac Sign : '), write(Zodiac), nl, nl.
```

Or, using, `format`:

```
write_item(details(Age,Name,Dob,Zodiac)) :-
    format('Name : ~w~NDate of Birth : ~w~NAge : ~w~NZodiac Sign : ~w~2N',
           [Name, Dob, Age, Zodiac]).
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but it gives an error.                             "ERROR: list_ascending/0: Undefined procedure: write_details/1".

Comment: @Daybreaker check it again. I fixed a typo.

Comment: @mbratch Wouldn't this be a good use case for the `format` predicates, or is there a particular reason you're opting for write here?

Comment: @aBathologist yes, `format` would be well-suited here I think. I was being a little lazy and taking the dumb way.

Comment: @mbratch Funny, I was starting to rationalize your use `write` on the grounds that it lets you reflect the desired formatting, whereas `format` forces a single long atom... :)

Comment: @aBathologist yeah, perhaps it is a bit of a trade here. Sometimes I just like simple, on a whim. :)